# Comparing n values in a single array

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

So I have a associative array that looks like the following:

```
   #items: array:84 [
0 => {#513
  +"name": "Spencer, Heaney and Von"
  +"id": 49
  +"lon": 40.68
  +"lat": 90.25
  +"catId": 2
  +"locId": 49
  +"distance": 48.796277782319
}
1 => {#514
  +"name": "Yost-Terry"
  +"id": 16
  +"lon": 40.07
  +"lat": 90.99
  +"catId": 2
  +"locId": 16
  +"distance": 52.598218030179
}
2 => {#515
  +"name": "Mills-Okuneva"
  +"id": 98
  +"lon": 40.84
  +"lat": 89.79
  +"catId": 1
  +"locId": 98
  +"distance": 59.083838249165
}
3 => {#516
  +"name": "D'Amore Ltd"
  +"id": 67
  +"lon": 40.88
  +"lat": 89.82
  +"catId": 1
  +"locId": 67
  +"distance": 61.538239638491
}
4 => {#517
  +"name": "D'Amore Ltd"
  +"id": 67
  +"lon": 40.88
  +"lat": 89.82
  +"catId": 2
  +"locId": 67
  +"distance": 61.538239638491
}
5 => {#518
  +"name": "Kuvalis, Denesik and Terry"
  +"id": 14
  +"lon": 41.03
  +"lat": 90.05
  +"catId": 1
  +"locId": 14
  +"distance": 71.218957454573
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is iterate through each location and check if the value after it is the same, or the next two values are the same, all the way to the next n values being the same.

So basically if a user passes 4 categories in then it will take the first locations name then check the next 3 locations names and see if they are the same, if so it adds all instances of a location with that name to a collection.

(Note this is faker generated data so the location "Labadie-Bauch" wont have the same catId in all 4 entries the live data)

The following code is my attempt at solving this, which isn't working. I believe this will work for if a user only passes 2 categories but not if they pass n categories.

```
$final = collect();

dd($locations);
for($i = 0; $i < count($locations);$i++){
    for($j = 1; $j < count($request->categories);$j++){
        if($locations[$i]->name == $locations[$i+$j]->name){
            //add to final collection
        }
    }
}
dd($final);
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Everything except for the location at index 5 should be in the collection?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, based on this small part of the data. The whole thing has 83 entries.

Comment: I'm not clear on the implication of the categories. Can you post an example of what you mean? With the above example, if only two categories were selected, would only two of the three `Labadie-Bauch` locations be selected? This isn't clear.

Comment: That data is messy I will delete the above part of the array and post a more clear section of it with a explanation.

Comment: @fubar I added a less messy version of the data, so basically because 2 categories were searched on the most a data set should be able to return is two instances of the location, since those categories are 1 and 2 I return all instances of the locations with categories one and two. What I want to do is make another collection with a list of all locations that have both of the categories not just one. On this datset then I would need to get back both instances of `D'Amore Ltd`. But this needs to be able to be scalable, so n categories.

Comment: So you only want to return locations that match all of the categories? If that's the case, surely the fact that the locations are consequtive doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, and they should be in order no matter what because that’s how I’m retrieving them from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an especially pretty solution, as it involves looping over the data three times.

```
$locations = [/* ... */];
$categories = [1, 2];
$collection = [];

// Reduce locations to an array categories, grouped by location name
$grouped = array_reduce($locations, function ($grouped, $location) {
    $grouped[$location->name][] = $location->catId;
    return $grouped;
}, []);

// Filter the location groups to remove any locations that do not match all categories
$grouped = array_filter($grouped, function ($_categories) use ($categories) {
    return ! array_diff($categories, $_categories);
});

// Append locations with matching name and category to collection
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    if (isset($grouped[$location->name]) && in_array($location->catId, $categories)) {
        $collection[] = $location;
    }
}


var_dump($collection);
```

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/mBZZn

I notice that you're using Laravel, so if the `$locations` are in a `Collection`, you may be able to chain some of this logic using the available `Collection` methods.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry for the late response, I haven't had time to test your solution but the logic looks sound and I'm sure it will lead me in the right direction. Midterm week has really slowed down my development..

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, however you could try looking at combining `array_unique()` with `array_diff_key()`. That'll give you a list of all NON unique entries in the array.

Something like:

```
array = array(
    1 => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
    3 => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
    4 => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
    5 => array('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'), 
    6 => array('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
    7 => array('h', 'i', 'j', 'k')
);

$unique = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
$not_unique = array_diff_key($array, $unique);
```

unique returns:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "g"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "h"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "i"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "j"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "k"
  }
}
```

and not_unique returns:

```
array(3) {
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "g"
  }
}
```

You can combine the two arrays to get your collection of N instances, and ignore single entries. Note the array KEYS on the results. You can use these to your advantage.